# Get values from selected CustomTile SAPUI5

Tags: tiles, sapui5

I have a product catalog made with CustomTile Control. When I press one tile, I want to go to a details page. For that I need to know some of the values that are on the pressed tile, which I'm not able to.

Here is the code for the tile and the binding:

```
    var sServiceUrl = "/sap/opu/odata/sap/ztestefardas_srv/"; //URL do serviço oDATA
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(sServiceUrl);
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel);
```

OData.read("/sap/opu/odata/sap/ztestefardas_srv/catalogo",

```
        function (response){
    for(var key in response.results) {
        var value = response.results[key];

  var oImg =new sap.ui.commons.Image({
      width :"160px",
      height :"160px"
      }).setSrc(value["img"]);
  oImg.addStyleClass("img_cat");

  var oMatxt =new sap.ui.commons.TextView({
    text: value["matxt"],
    width: "200px"
    }).addStyleClass("matxt");

  var oAtr =new sap.ui.commons.TextView({
    text: "Atribuídos: "+value["n_atr"],
    width: "200px"
    }).addStyleClass("second_line");

  if (value["n_dis"] > 0){
    var oDis =new sap.ui.commons.TextView({
        text: "Disponíveis: "+value["n_dis"],
        width: "200px"
        }).addStyleClass("second_line_disp");
  } else {
    var oDis =new sap.ui.commons.TextView({
        text: "Disponíveis: "+value["n_dis"],
        width: "200px"
        }).addStyleClass("second_line");
  }

  var oPtxt =new sap.ui.commons.TextView({
    text: "Próximo levantamento:",
    width: "200px"
    }).addStyleClass("third_line");

  var oPlev =new sap.ui.commons.TextView({
    text: value["p_lev"],
    width: "200px"
    }).addStyleClass("third_line");

  var oLayout = new sap.ui.commons.layout.VerticalLayout({
content: [oImg,oMatxt,oAtr,oDis,oPtxt,oPlev]
```

});

```
  var oTile = new sap.m.CustomTile({
    content:oLayout,
    press: function(oEvento){  



        //missing code to get values from selected tile
        oNavContainer.to(Page2);
        } 
            }).addStyleClass('sapMTile');


        oContainer.addTile(oTile); 
    }});
```

I've tried with the table attach row selection change way, but it's not working too.
Can you please help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to make this work.

within the FOR that I used to read the data from the odata:

`oTile.data("matnr", value["Matnr"]);
  oTile.data("matxt", value["Itmfdx"]);
  oTile.data("n_dis", value["n_dis"]);
  oTile.data("n_atr", value["n_atr"]);
  oTile.data("endda", value["Endda"]);
  oTile.data("itmfd", value["Itmfd"]);`

these `value["xpto"]` are the keys from the response results `(OData.read("/sap/opu/odata/sap/zmm_fardamentos_srv/CatalogoSet?sap-ui-language=PT",`

```
        function (response){
    for(var key in response.results) {
        var value = response.results[key];)
```

Then, I created a function for the attachPress event of oTile with these:

```
oTile.attachPress( function(){
          sap.ui.getCore().getControl("selimg").setSrc(this.data("img"));
          sap.ui.getCore().getControl("bigpic").setSrc(this.data("img"));
          sap.ui.getCore().getControl("nome_material").setText(this.data("matxt"));
          sap.ui.getCore().getControl("itmfd_var").setText(this.data("itmfd"));
          sap.ui.getCore().getControl("atr_det").setText(this.data("n_atr"));
          sap.ui.getCore().getControl("disp_det").setText(this.data("n_dis"));
          sap.ui.getCore().getControl("lev_data").setText(this.data("endda"));
```

the names within getControl are the id of the variables that will hold the values.

Maybe this is not the fanciest way, but it sure works :)

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code in your function (response) method:

```
var valueModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({
                "Value": "##your value here##",
            });
oLayout.setModel(valueModel);
```

Add the following code in the press function handler:

```
var oLayout = oEvento.getSource().getContent();
var value = oLayout .getModel().getProperty("/Value");
```

Then you can get values from the CustomTile by using data binding to get the value your want.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, your way works too, but I found another one in the meantime. thank you!